# how to recover the original dimensions of an image

Tags: javascript, html

Im using this.

```
        <div class="col-md ml-md-5">
           <img id="imgPreview" class="img" width="350" height="350" />
        </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var img = document.querySelector('img');
        //var img = document.getElementById('imgPreview');
        var altoDefinido = img.height; // 350
        var altoOriginal = img.naturalHeight; // 512
        var anchoDefinido = img.width; // 350
        var anchoOriginal = img.naturalWidth; // 512
        
                   
        document.getElementById("lblDimensiones").innerText  = altoOriginal.toString()+" x "+ anchoOriginal.toString();
        document.getElementById("inpDimensiones").value = altoOriginal.toString()+" x "+ anchoOriginal.toString();

</script>
```

But "var altoOriginal = img.naturalHeight;" always return 32, though the image dimensions is 512

Comment: You are just missing the `src` attribute for your image.

Comment: I assign the src below with script code.

Comment: What returns? I don't see any `return` or `console.log`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The actual dimensions may be different if the browser degrades resolution because of the device of user, see this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/naturalWidth#sect1)

Comment: Forgive me but I still don’t see you setting the source anywhere.